# Where to find information about Italy - Czech - Poland migration?

Tags: immigration, poland

Reviewing my grandfather's documents I found evidences that his family arrived in Poland after some generations that left Italy and lived in the (actual) Czech republic.

Where can I find information about it, like birth registries or census data ?

Edit:
The time frame would be from 1780 to 1900, and would be related to north Italy, Prague and Warsaw...

Comment: Please update your question, to include a time frame.  Also, note that the boundary of Czech and Poland has moved a lot, so it is possible they were in the same place?

Comment: Varsovia == Warszawa (Warsaw, Poland's Capital City)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Most of the Czech Republic records are now available online. Introduction to the Using Online Czech Records series will teach you how to use the Czech digitized records.

This is the first item that I noticed under **News** when I opened the [relevant page of the Wiki at *FamilySearch Learn*](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Czech_Republic). (The link from the Wiki is to a video tutorial!)

There are similarly detailed pages on Poland and Italy (and most other countries).

Because of the focus on how many million (or even billion) records that FamilySearch is supposed to have, it is easy to overlook their extensive library (with an online catalogue) and huge suite of learning resources including the wiki. These parts of the site do not provide information about your ancestors but rather focus on how to make best use of information held elsewhere. They are a great place to start searching.